# How to save the value of one variable to another variable in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, datetime, oracle-apex, trim

I have two items in Oracle APEX and I want to make one item to have by default part of value of another item. I have tried by using SQL function `TRIM`:

```
SELECT TRIM('HH24:MI ' FROM TIME_AND_DATE) AS DATE FROM BILL;

TIME_AND_DATE - (format mask: DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI)
DATE          - (format mask: DD-MM-YYYY)
```

But it returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TIME_AND_DATE`  columns datatype is `DATE` and you want to put only date part of it into a variable, then `TRUNC` it (not `TRIM`).

```
SQL> select sysdate date_and_time,
  2         trunc(sysdate) truncated
  3  from dual;

DATE_AND_TIME       TRUNCATED
------------------- -------------------
15.05.2020 15:07:12 15.05.2020 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Next step is just the presentation; use `TO_CHAR` (or format mask in front end (Apex?)) to display it as you want, e.g.

```
SQL> select to_char(trunc(sysdate), 'dd-fmmonth-yyyy') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------
15-svibanj-2020

SQL>
```

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work. It returns me current date, so if my date_and_time is not current, date will still be current.

Comment: I used `SYSDATE` just as example as I don't have your tables nor data; there's no TIME_AND_DATE column in my database. Therefore, I used SYSDATE to show *how* to do that. You'd use your own column.

Comment: But I don't need any other column except TIME_AND_DATE

Comment: I didn't say you do :) Maybe it would be easier to assist if you created sample page on apex.oracle.com and provided login credentials so that we could have a look what you did and what problem you have.

Comment: All I can see is an empty page, no items there. Also, I'd need *developer's* credentials to be able to do something about it. If all I can do is look at it, it is as if you posted a screenshot.

Comment: OK, I'm connected. I'll have a look and let you know.

Comment: Which values would you want to see? "DATE OF ISSUE" is currently "5/18/2020" as well as "DUE DATE", while "DATE AND TIME OF ISSUE" is "18-05-2020 21:51".

Comment: You said "DATE OF ISSUE must be DATE AND TIME OF ISSUE but with the date part only by default". What does that mean, "only by default"?

Comment: If "DATE AND TIME OF ISSUE" is "18-05-2020 21:51"  I want to have "DATE OF ISSUE = 18-05-2020

Comment: by deafault I mean that I don't have to write it, it will have that value automatically

Comment: Aha. If I understood you correctly, you don't need DATUM_IZDAVANJA at all because you'll use VRIJEME_IZDAVANJA column for both purposes: one for date (dd.mm.yyyy) and another for time (hh24:mi). If that's so, instead of region's "Source type = table", use "Source type = SQL query" and alias "VRIJEME_IZDAVANJA AS DATUM_IZDAVANJA"; also, set desired format masks. I did that on Page 2, region "Bill by Littlefoot". Have a look, please.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using DATUM_IZDAVANJA on some other report, so that's why I needed this.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should drop that column; you just don't need it in this report as you take both date (for DATE OF ISSUE) and date + time (for DATE AND TIME OF ISSUE) from the same column: VRIJEME_IZDAVANJA.